Reported speech and possible changes
Direct speech: He is going to play when she arrives
Indirect speech:
a) He said he is going to play when she arrives = him playing and her arrival are still yet to happen in the future
b) He said he was going to play when she arrived =  him playing and her arrrival are either yet to happen or they already happened.
I'd like to ask you if my version C is also possible, valid and if my understaing of its possible meaning is correct.
c) He said he was going to play when she comes = so, here we either believe that will play or it may be that he won't but her arrival is still to happen.
Is my third version correct?

What kind of playing is this? The answer is likely to be different if he's e.g. playing background music or playing tennis against her.

(a) could also be "He says he is going to play when she arrives" (says because the statement is still relevant to the present moment of waiting for her arrival).

Not pictured here: "he said he would play when she arrives." While I'm not going to commit myself to saying that C is impossible, this seems more likely.

"He said he is" sounds unnatural to me, though I could imagine that people say it. In ordinary circumstances, he would have been talking about his plans (what he was going to do) as of the time he spoke, rather than his plans as of the time you are now speaking. So he could only have said what he was going to do.

Yes, your interpretation is essentially correct. She is not here yet.
Other ways of saying the same thing are

He said that he intends to play [when / once / after] she arrives.

His intention is now, it may change in the future.
It says nothing about what he will do if she doesn't come, he may still play regardless.
And whilst he intends [wants] to play at the time he says this, once she arrives they may decide to do something else instead.
